# Getting latest in Source Control locks up Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have 3 installs of Visual Studio (2010, 2012, 2013).

Today out of nowhere all three instances will lock up when I attempt to 'Get Latest' in Source Control. I know I'm able to connect to our TFS Server because I can still check in changes.

Has anyone ever experienced an issue like this? Currently I am completely unable to get latest versions of projects.

Comment: are you using different workspaces for each VS version? have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Hi, so checking in files works fine but "Get Latest" locks? Is there modal dialog hidden somewhere?

Comment: So in case anyone comes along this looking for a solution: I just let it run for about 20 minutes. Windows was saying the process was locked up, however after the 20 minutes it successfully pulled latest. After this happened Getting Latest returned to taking the expected amount of time.. Very weird.